# Is it possible to deserialize and serialize json object in different propety names?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let us say I have this class:

```
public class Resource
{
    [JsonProperty(propertyName: "address")]
    public Domain.DTO.Address Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

The Json string value looks like:

```
{
  .
  .
  .
  "resourceSets":[
     {
        "estimatedTotal":1,
        "resources":[
           {
              .
              .
              .
              "address":{
                 "UserLocation":null,
                 "adminDistrict":"National Capital Region",
                 "adminDistrict2":"Third District NCR",
                 "locality":"Caloocan City",
                 "postalCode":null,
                 "addressLine":"Yellow Bell Ext",
                 "formattedAddress":"Yellow Bell Ext, Caloocan City, Philippines",
                 "neighborhood":"Barangay 161",
                 "landmark":null,
                 "countryRegion":"Philippines"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

This deserializes properly. But when serializing the Resource class, I want some of the properties like 'Addresses' to be serialized as 'Addresses' and not 'address'.

I have tried using DataMember but didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to use `'address'` when deserialising but `'Addresses'` when serialising?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[JsonProperty(propertyName: "address")]
```

is making it serialise as `"address"`.

Remove the attribute and it'll serialise to the C# Property name.

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Class);
```

Comment: If I do that, it won't deserialize the address. :)

Comment: It will. `Newsonsoft.Json` ignores case.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!!! Didn't know that. :)) By the way I changed Addresses to Address, and it works now without jsonProperty name.

Comment: @fiberOptics I do not understand the problem you can give the property name as you like.You can change the adddress to Addresses in propertyName or it is not case insensitive?

Comment: @BassamAlugili Sorry to confused you. Actually my first problem was that I wasn't able to deserialize `address` into `Resource.Addresses` that is why I used `[JsonProperty(propertyName: "address")]` and still I want it serialized using `Addresses` (which will not work). But since Sam Leach said `Newsonsoft.Json ignores case` then I don't need [JsonProperty]. I just have to changed `Addresses` into `Address`.